# Duplicate object in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to duplicate an object in Core Data, in that it has all the same information (but a new, unique ID) as the initial object, but can be changed and manipulated in the future as its own object, without impacting the initial object's data.

```
        guard let initialObject = self.fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) else {
            fatalError("Attempt to configure cell without a managed object")
        }

        let object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Object", into: self.moc) as! Object

        object.data = initialObject.data
        object.name = initialObject.name?.appending(" copy")
        object.creationDate = Date()
        object.id = generateID(length: 27)

        do {
            try self.moc.save()
            success(true)
        } catch {
            success(false)
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

However, when I change `data` on the newly created object, the initialObject also receives the data change. This does not happen if I change `name`. The type of `data` is an array of a custom object, a transformable under the entity.

I don't understand why this happens and what steps I need to take in order to be able to have this functionality where the duplicate object and the duplicated object can exist independently, but the duplicate object can initially start with the same data as the duplicated object. I incorrectly thought this behavior would only occur at the level of `Object`, not on its variables.

Comment: Are you changing the array or one of the elements in the array?  If the array contains class instances then those are reference types and so the two `data` arrays contain references to the same collection of objects. You may need to perform a deep copy whereby your new `data` is an array of copies of your original array contents.

Comment: @Paulw11 Using your guidance I was able to solve the issue, if you answer this question and include some sample code, I will accept it as an answer. Otherwise, I will answer my own question the same.